# Odoo error on installation of Module - XMLSyntaxError: None

Tags: python, odoo

hello I am trying to install a new module in odoo created by me and it does not let me install it when I remove it in the file manifest.py the data key with the xml lets me install it correctly ... The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 642, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 334, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 327, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 942, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 899, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 412, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 486, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 377, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 270, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 96, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 900, in convert_xml_import
    etree.parse(os.path.join(config['root_path'],'import_xml.rng' )))
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3197, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64816)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1571, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92729)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1600, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:93013)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1500, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92076)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1047, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:88976)
  File "parser.pxi", line 577, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:84385)
  File "parser.pxi", line 676, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:85488)
  File "parser.pxi", line 627, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:84981)
XMLSyntaxError: None
```

Comment: Check that the xml files in your module are well formed xml. It is hard to answer or comment more because you did not provide much content from your module or the xml data inside module. If the problem persist, please include more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check your xml syntax, just put them in an online xml checker when this doesn't work, just comment out the different xml files and see where your error comes from. And share that piece with us.